# java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException Coming in SFTP

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, java-security

Hi i am trying a simple sftp, but i m getting an error while establishing. connection, i am using **maverick-legacy-client-all** jar available at 
https://www.sshtools.com/en/products/java-ssh-client this code was working fine with release 1.6.9 but it failed when i updated it to 1.6.17.

I also tried going through there jar [changes doc here](https://www.sshtools.com/hypersocket/api/versions/changes/Maverick%20Legacy%20Client/), there was few notes regarding to my exception *DiffieHellmanGroupExchange Algo* related changes but i failed to understand them clearly.

```
public void connect() throws SshException, IOException,
        SftpStatusException, ChannelOpenException {

    SshConnector con = SshConnector.createInstance();
    con.setKnownHosts(new SftpHostKeyVerification());
    // Tries SSH2 first and fallback to SSH1 if its not available
    con.setSupportedVersions(SshConnector.SSH1 | SshConnector.SSH2);
    /*Error coming here, in con.connect*/

    this.ssh = con
            .connect(new SocketTransport(this.host, DEFAULT_SSH_PORT),
                    this.userName);

    PasswordAuthentication pwd = new PasswordAuthentication();
    pwd.setPassword(this.passwod);
    int isLoggedIn = this.ssh.authenticate(pwd);
    if (SshAuthentication.COMPLETE == isLoggedIn) {
        this.client = new SftpClient(this.ssh);
    } else {
        throw new IOException("[Authentication failure] login status: "
                + isLoggedIn);
    }
}
```

Exception Log:

```
com.maverick.ssh.SshException: com.maverick.ssh.SshException
    at com.maverick.ssh.components.jce.client.DiffieHellmanGroupExchangeSha1.performClientExchange(DiffieHellmanGroupExchangeSha1.java:315)
    at com.maverick.ssh2.TransportProtocol.performKeyExchange(TransportProtocol.java:1424)
    at com.maverick.ssh2.TransportProtocol.processMessage(TransportProtocol.java:1835)
    at com.maverick.ssh2.TransportProtocol.startTransportProtocol(TransportProtocol.java:348)
    at com.maverick.ssh2.Ssh2Client.connect(Ssh2Client.java:146)
    at com.maverick.ssh.SshConnector.connect(SshConnector.java:649)
    at com.maverick.ssh.SshConnector.connect(SshConnector.java:471)
    at com.tekelec.ems.util.SftpImpl.connect(SftpImpl.java:73)
    at com.tekelec.ems.eagle.measurement.WriterThread.run(WriterThread.java:93)

 Caused by: com.maverick.ssh.SshException: Failed to generate DH value: Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive) [java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException]
    at com.maverick.ssh.components.jce.client.DiffieHellmanGroupExchangeSha1.performClientExchange(DiffieHellmanGroupExchangeSha1.java:250)
    ... 8 more

Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.DHKeyPairGenerator.initialize(DHKeyPairGenerator.java:120)
    at java.security.KeyPairGenerator$Delegate.initialize(KeyPairGenerator.java:658)
    at java.security.KeyPairGenerator.initialize(KeyPairGenerator.java:400)
    at com.maverick.ssh.components.jce.client.DiffieHellmanGroupExchangeSha1.performClientExchange(DiffieHellmanGroupExchangeSha1.java:240)
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This because the default key exchange algorithm was changed to a more secure algorithm between those versions and you have not included all of the 3rd party dependencies that are provided in the lib folder of the Maverick Legacy Client distribution. This folder contains the BouncyCastle JCE provider which if added to the class path will resolve this issue.

The problem you are facing is that without the BouncyCastle JCE provider or a suitable JCE provider that supports large Diffie Hellman primes you will not be able to generate a large prime for the updated, more secure key exchange method.

Comment: As you mentioned that _this folder contains the BouncyCastle JCE provider which if added to the class path will resolve this issue_ please guide me which all other jars do i need to add from this package.

Comment: BouncyCastle JCE. After one day and a half trying to figure out why Jsch got me that damn DH KeypairGenerator exception, adding bcprov-jdk15on-165.jar and bcprov-ext-jdk15on-165.jar finally did the trick. Thanks a lot @Lee David. So, for those interested in connecting to an SFTP server through Java using a key pair authentication, you'll need Jsch, Apache commons FSV2 if you choose to go this way (you'll need Jsch anyway to have the sftp scheme, which for some reason Apache hasn't), and of course Bouncycastle to have the DH algorithm id that's what you need.

Answer (score 1):

i believe this a very serious condition occurring to many coders, 
also i would like to thank [Lee David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5134621/lee-david-painter) here for the advice here. i was able to handle this situation by *adding Bouncy Castle JCE 3rd party jar available in maverick lib folder*.

Before this i was trying to edit my java.security file as suggested in other post but this was much easy way, also these Bouncy Castle jars come bundled in Maverick official release, so no worries on that part to.